# How can I use powershell to rename files with padded zeros

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I need to limit the files affected to Example*.pdf. The files have 1-3 digits in the names and I need to standardize them. So Example_1.pdf -> Example_001.pdf while Example_100.pdf -> Example_100.pdf

The first part renamed files to Example.1.pdf so I could parse them with a single delimiter, but it gave me errors on the second step (cmdlet rename-item at command pipeline position 1 supply values for the following parameters: path)

```
Get-ChildItem of* | rename-item -newname { $_.Name -replace '_','.' }
Get-ChildItem of* | 
    foreach {
        $nameArray = $_.Split('.')
        $ExampleNumber = $nameArray[1]
        rename-item -path $Path -newname $nameArray[0]+$ExampleNumber+$nameArray[2]
    }
```

But if I can get something like this to work then I can play around with $ExampleNumber

Then I tried using regular expressions. Had this worked it would have padded the single digit files and then I could make a second pass for double digit files. But it didn't rename anything.

```
Get-ChildItem ex* | rename-item -newname { $_ -replace '(.*)(\d{1})\.pdf', 'Example_0$2.pdf'}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Normally using `[String]::Format("{0:00#}", 1)` will append 0 on the number if necessary.
```
rename-item -path $Path -newname $nameArray[0]+[String]::Format("{0:00#}", $ExampleNumber)+$nameArray[2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the `$_` inside the `-NewName` block is of type `FileInfo`.

Here's my suggestion:

```
Get-ChildItem ex* | Rename-Item -NewName {
  [void]($_.Name -match "\d+")
  $_.Name -replace "\d+", (([int]$Matches[0]).ToString("000"))
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
Get-ChildItem ex* |
 Rename-Item -NewName {
   $_.Name -replace "\d+", (([int][regex]::match($_.Name, "\d+").value).ToString("000"))}
```